# How to set icon to an adobe air application

Tags: apache-flex, icons, air, taskbar

I am developing an Adobe Air app. I need to set an icon to the app so it is shown on the task bar. I added the icon tag to the descriptor file but it is not working and I really don't know why, any ideas?

Answer (score 11):

Two things that might be throwing you off:

1) the icons block is commented out by default in the auto-generated descriptor file, and is an easy thing to overlook

2) the icons specified in a descriptor file don't appear in the app unless you build a release build, and install the resulting .air file.  A debug build will only show the AIR icon.

At least these are the behaviors I experience in Flash Builder 4.

Answer (score 3):

Adding the icons to your application descriptor should do it.

However, icons come in different sizes.

For example:

```
<icon>
    <image16x16>/icons/app/icon_16.png</image16x16>
    <image29x29>/icons/app/icon_29.png</image29x29>
    <image32x32>/icons/app/icon_32.png</image32x32>
    <image36x36>/icons/app/icon_36.png</image36x36>
    <image48x48>/icons/app/icon_48.png</image48x48>
    <image57x57>/icons/app/icon_57.png</image57x57>
    <image72x72>/icons/app/icon_72.png</image72x72>
    <image114x114>/icons/app/icon_114.png</image114x114>
    <image128x128>/icons/app/icon_128.png</image128x128>
    <image512x512>/icons/app/icon_512.png</image512x512>
</icon>
```

If I'm not mistaken, the `32x32` icon should be the one that is displayed in the taskbar.
Obviously, make sure that you are referring to the correct path in your descriptor file.

Answer (score 1):

One more thing.  I just wasted over an hour on this:  For an iOS app, you won't see the icon when you drop the app into iTunes (at least not under Windows), but it will appear on your device!