# How do I use a custom icon for my Flex AIR app?

Tags: apache-flex, air

I'm trying to change the default icon of my Flex 4.5 AIR app for the desktop.

I tried modifying the `Main-app.xml` Adobe AIR Application Descriptor File Template file:

```
<icon>
    <image16x16>src/assets/app_icons/icon_016.png</image16x16>
    <image32x32>src/assets/app_icons/icon_032.png</image32x32>
    <image48x48>src/assets/app_icons/icon_048.png</image48x48>
    <image128x128>src/assets/app_icons/icon_128.png</image128x128>
</icon>
```

However, this does not seem to work, and I'm still seeing the default AIR icon when I run the app. I wonder if I got the relative path of the icons wrong?

Note: I tried `assets/app_icons/` path as well, and that doesn't work either.

Comment: Your question is a duplicate of [How to set icon to an adobe air application](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8215547/570918).  At least for the case of Flash Builder 4, the icons only appear when you export a release build and install your application.  This is probably the same behavior in FB4.5.

Comment: Ah, thanks :)
That post answers my question. I'll close this question, then.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set icon to an adobe air application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8213632/how-to-set-icon-to-an-adobe-air-application)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found the solution to this problem "303 app.xml icon file is missing in package"

1. create the ***assets*** folder inside ***src*** instead of application folder
2. try to put all versions of the icon sizes

   ```
   <!-- The icon the system uses for the application. For at least one resolution, 
   specify the path to a PNG file included in the AIR package. Optional. --><icon>
   <image16x16>assets/icon16.png</image16x16>
   <image32x32>assets/icon32.png</image32x32>
   <image48x48>assets/icon48.png</image48x48>
   <image72x72>assets/icon72.png</image72x72>
   <image128x128>assets/icon128.png</image128x128></icon>
   ```

Hope it helps

Comment: glad you solved it :-) Just: please don't copy the exact same post to several questions - chances are that either they don't really fit all or the questions are duplicates (and should be flagged as such)

Answer (score 0):

your path is wrong, try this:
`<image16x16>src/assets/app_icons/icon_016.png</image16x16>`