# How to set up an app iicon for TVOS using AS3 ?

Tags: actionscript-3, tvos

I have created an App for TVOS using AS3. But i am having trouble in setting up the app icon. Can anyone please suggest the steps on how to set up this icon using AS3.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to write something like this

```
<icon>
    <image16x16>icon-16.png</image16x16>
    <image32x32>icon-32.png</image32x32>
    <image48x48>icon-48.png</image48x48>
    <image128x128>icon-128.png</image128x128>
</icon>
```

Be sure to uncomment any commented line in the XML.

Here are some links you'll find useful:

- [TVOS documentation on app icons](https://developer.apple.com/tvos/human-interface-guidelines/icons-and-images/)
- [How to set icon to an adobe air application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8213632/how-to-set-icon-to-an-adobe-air-application)